# Python: split column when it contains certain word and append a string in the end

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column called `address`:

```
address
xxx City yyy road 17 number 8 floor west bank
ttt City iii road 1 number
ggg City kkk road 25 number 1 floor apple store
```

If the address contains `floor`, I need to split it and get the address before it. Since I also remove the `floor` itself, I have to append it back.

My code:

```
df['address'] = df.address.str.split('floor').str[0]+'floor'
```

Output:

```
xxx City yyy road 17 number 8 floor
ttt City iii road 1 number floor
ggg City kkk road 25 number 1 floor
```

My expected result:

```
xxx City yyy road 17 number 8 floor
ttt City iii road 1 number  #if the original address does not contain 'floor', don't do anything
ggg City kkk road 25 number 1 floor
```

Comment: The issue is that you are adding 'floor' whether or not it was in the original address string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add if check

```
def process_address(address):
    if 'floor' in address:
        return address.split('floor')[0].strip() + ' floor'
    else:
        return address

df['processed_address'] = df['address'].apply(process_address)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex replacement approach here:

```py
df["address"] = df["address"].str.replace(r'(?<=\bfloor)\s+.*', '', regex=True)
```

Check the running [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/JZnoMh/1).